# Where to put some view code in Cakely way

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi everyone and thanks for answering.

If i want to remove some code from a view for simplify it, what's the correct way?

I've created an element in Elements/model/some_code.ctp and call it from the view.ctp but my colleague suggests me to create a file in View/Controller/some_code.php and call it with an include in the view.ctp file.
The element that i've created isn't replicated in other parts of the app, i only move code here to simplify the readability of view.ctp file.

Is that correct?

Thank You all ;)

Better explain:

```
//index.ctp
[..some code..]
echo $this->element('box');
[..some code..]

//Element/box.ctp
<?php if (isset($n)) { ?>
<div class="row">
<?php
    echo $this->BoxStat->drawBox('Title', $n[1], 'green', array(
        array('name' => 'Tot', 'link' => "/model/action", 'color' => '', 'number' => $n[2]),
        array('name' => 'Free', 'link' => "/model/action", 'color' => 'green', 'number' => $n[3]),
        array('name' => 'Full', 'link' => "/model/action", 'color' => 'grey', 'number' => $n[4]),
    ));

    [..repeat..]
?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Using elements for chunks of view code is completely normal; using include and putting php files in view folders - is not. You don't clarify what's in the element, if it's not template code it should probably be a helper.

Comment: What your colleague suggests breaks the MVC pattern.  Occasionally you might come across some weird problem where breaking from MVC is the best answer, but I doubt that this is one of them.  Breaking up complicated views into many elements, even if they're only used once, is a perfectly fine way to try to increase readability.  But it really depends on what exactly you're doing to figure out what is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the cake way to do this is with elements for many reasons:

- Elements can be cached with ease
- By using elements, you can choose the variables to send or overwrite the values of current view variables
- Elements does not share variable scope in same way include() or require() does inside a view.